# Ubuntu 16.04 install fails upgrade, fails install from bootable usb

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 16.04

I have an intel i7 CPU, geforce gtx 970 GPU, and an asus motherboard with 3 monitors.  I had a working version of Ubuntu 15.10 with CUDA as the video driver.

Then, I chose to upgrade the system...

After upgrading to 16.04, the system loaded up, and displayed the login screen on one of the three monitors.

After typing in the password, the system fails and does a restart of what looks like either some "shell" and maybe X (I can't tell--the screen goes dark and some text displays for a split second).  Then, the login screen appears again, this time with a mouse that is very choppy (like a bad remote desktop connection).

So, the upgrade failed.  Next, I downloaded the 16.04 image and made a bootable USB.  The USB version of the operating system runs great--all three monitors are displaying, the installer goes through the prompts...but then, after installing, everything goes to hell.  I select the option for automatic login...and, on startup, I get a black screen with a mouse (that works fine--smooth motion) on monitor 1, no signal in the other monitors, and the ubuntu error reporting message flashes up briefly every few seconds. That is it--no other interactivity.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Did you try booting with the "nomodeset" option, and then install the proprietary Nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something incompatible with 16.04 in your home directory.  You can check this by working with the console and creating a clean home directory.

You can test this by creating a new userID.  You can do this from the console with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.  Then login.

Use this command to create a new user:

```
$ sudo adduser [newuser]
```

The `[newuser]` will be the name of the new user without the brackets.

You may have to reload the login manager with `sudo service lightdm restart` so that it will see the added user.

Now login as the new user.

If this works, while from the newuser's account you can work to fix the problems that you have with your regular account.

**Fixing the flawed account:**

First add the new user account to the sudoer access.  Then from a console perform these steps:

Change directories to the failed login (I'll refer to it as `youraccount`).

```
$ cd ~youraccount
$ cd ..
$ sudo mv youraccount youraccount.store
$ mkdir youraccount
$ sudo chown youraccount youraccount
```

If logging in as the newuser worked, you should be able to now login as your account.  Now you can systematically move or copy your configurations from your failed login account to the new directory.  Or you can study which components are causing the problem and deal directly with those.

By the way, the problem configuration is almost always something very simple.  It might just be a permission bit of your home folder.  It also might be a problem with the ownership of the`.Xauthority` file.